# Change angle of text on axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to change the angle of the text on an axis in XlsxWriter?
In Excel, you would do this:
*Format Axis > Alignment > Text Layout > Custom Angle: -70*

And I think a VB macro would look like this:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = -70  ' degrees
```

I don't see anything in the [XlsxWriter docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html) about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `set_x_axis` (set_y_axis) method for such cases i think.

```
chart.set_x_axis({'name_font': {'bold': True, 'italic': True}})
```

Here is [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html?highlight=axis#set_y_axis) into docs.

Comment: I don't see anything there about setting the text angle. I found it though. It talks uses the term rotation not angle, which is why I had difficulty finding it. `chart.set_x_axis({'num_font':  {'rotation': 45}})`(https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html#chart-formatting)

Comment: 'italic' font has already angle. Also you can use 'rotation'.