# Rotate the axis of an excel chart using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

there
 I'm trying to using openpyxl to deal with Excel Data.Drawing the picture out and exporting them is OK.But the x_axis is not pretty enough,I want to rotate that but haven't found the solution in the doc.

Here is the solution using XlsxWriter:[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427877/change-angle-of-text-on-axis).

My Code is something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    LineChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
    shapes,
    text,
    axis)
wb = load_workbook('text.xlsx')
ws = wb.active  
c5 = ScatterChart()
x = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row)
for i in range(3,5):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row)
series = Series(values, xvalues=x, title_from_data=True)
# series.marker.symbol = 'triangle'
c5.series.append(series)
c5.x_axis.number_format='yyyy/mm/dd'
c5.x_axis.title = 'Date'
```

Thanks all!

My Python version is 3.5.2 and openpyxl is 2.4.0

----------------newcode to rotate but make file broken and need repaired

```
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import RichTextProperties
c5.x_axis.txPr = RichText(bodyPr=RichTextProperties(rot="-2700000"))
```

------------- code in Excel xml

```
<valAx>
            some codes here
    <txPr>
        <a:bodyPr rot="-1350000" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>

    </txPr>
    <crossAx val="20"/>
</valAx>
```

codes above breaks the file until I add these in it

```
<txPr>
    <a:bodyPr rot="-1350000" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
    <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
        <a:pPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:defRPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
        </a:pPr>
        <a:endParaRPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" lang="zh-CN"/>
    </a:p>
</txPr>
```

Comment: The solution in openpyxl is similar to that proposed for Visual Basic. You'll need to look more closely at the OOXML specification.

Comment: I'm So sorry that I'm new to VBA and openpyxl. Do you mean COM in Excel? I checked objects in VBA editor of Excel and find no help.Will you please give me more details? thanks a lot

Comment: I finally unzipped my xlsx file,and find something that represents angle.But I'm not sure because after I finished ,the file is shown broken some way.  @CharlieClark   ,new codes are in the main body

Comment: According to the specification "This simple type represents an angle in 60,000ths of a degree. Positive angles are clockwise (i.e., towards the positive y axis); negative angles are counter-clockwise (i.e., towards the negative y axis)." You'll have to look at the generated XML and compare it with the original you're trying to match. This stuff is horrible.

Comment: I unzipped the original and the rotated xlsx,checked /xl/charts/chart1.xml,It changed from 114 lines to 2999 lines! It is definitely a different one...

Comment: ok,here it is ,I need one step further. Using the code above,I got one broken excel file.I unzipped that.find the xl/charts/chart1.xml.After doing some edition ,I finally make that happen. The question is I dont know how to add that using openpyxl.@CharlieClark Thanks a lot.The code are placed above

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Charlie Clark
I finally get the answer
The adding codes are below:

```
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import  RichTextProperties,Paragraph,ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties
c5.x_axis.txPr = RichText(bodyPr=RichTextProperties(anchor="ctr",anchorCtr="1",rot="-2700000",
           spcFirstLastPara="1",vertOverflow="ellipsis",wrap="square"),
        p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=CharacterProperties()), endParaRPr=CharacterProperties())])
```

It is a little complicated ,But can be learned from openpyxl documentation

txPr is typed RichText,and it consists of (bodyPr and p),bodyPr defines it's properties, p is a sequence and decides if the axis will be shown or not.

it can rotate the x_axis of the chart -45 degrees.

It also might be a bit more convenient to make a copy of an existing property and set its rotation:

```
chart.x_axis.title = 'Date'
chart.x_axis.txPr = deepcopy(chart.x_axis.title.text.rich)
chart.x_axis.txPr.properties.rot = "-2700000"
```