# Axis text orientation on openpyxl chart

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm generating a ScatterChart with pyopenxl from a pandas dataframe.

I am trying to change the rotation of the text in the X axis to 270º but I cannot found documentation about how to do it.

This is the code to generate the chart.

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
import pandas as pd

def generate_chart_proyeccion(writer_sheet, col_to_graph, start_row, end_row, title):
    """
    Construct a new chart object

    :param writer_sheet: Worksheet were is data located
    :param col_to_graph: Column of data to be plotted
    :param start_row: Row where data starts
    :param end_row: Row where data ends
    :param title: Chart title
    :return: returns a chart object
    """
    chart = ScatterChart()
    chart.title = title
    chart.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm HH:MM'
    chart.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
    chart.x_axis.title = "Date"
    chart.y_axis.title = "Value"
    chart.legend.position = "b"
    data = Reference(writer_sheet, min_col=col_to_graph, max_col=col_to_graph, min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row)
    data_dates = Reference(writer_sheet, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=start_row, max_row=end_row) # Corresponde a la columna con la fecha
    serie = Series(data, data_dates, title_from_data=True)
    chart.series.append(serie)
    return chart

# Write data to excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1), columns=['Value'], index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10,freq='T'))
start_row = 1 # Row to start writing df in excel
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=start_row) 
end_row = start_row + len(df) # End of the data
chart = generate_chart_proyeccion(writer.sheets["Sheet1"], 2, start_row, end_row, "A title")
# Añado gráfico a excel
writer.sheets["Sheet1"].add_chart(chart, "C2")  
writer.save()
```

This is the output chart that I got.

[image]

This is the output chart that I want.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately nothing like as simple as it should be because in the specification this is one of the areas where the schema changes from SpreadsheetDrawingML to DrawingML, which is far more abstract. The best thing to do is actually create two sample files and compare them. In this case this difference is in `rot` or `rotation` attribute of the `txPr` or `textProperties` of the axis. This is covered in § 21.1.2.1.1 of the OOXML specification.

The following code should work, but might require you to create a `TextProperties` object:

`chart.x_axis.textProperties.bodyProperties.rot = -5400000`

Comment: I've tried this idea but chart.x_axis.textProperties should be of openpyxl.chart.text.RichText type. However I tried to use it:
`import openpyxl
t = openpyxl.chart.text.RichText();
chart.x_axis.textProperties = t
t.properties.rot = -5400000
`
But when I open the resulting document Excel says that the drawing is damaged and is not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question - this SO post by @oldhumble solved it for me - please see [Rotate the axis of an excel chart using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146418/rotate-the-axis-of-an-excel-chart-using-openpyxl/40209930#40209930)