# Rotate x-axis labels in a chart using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, xml, openpyxl

The code below generates a simple barchart using openpyxl.

[image]

Now I'm struggling to rotate the x-axis labels. Is perhaps an XML solution possible? IS there a way to be able to locate that particular piece of XML code and adjust?

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

# Create a workbook and activate a sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

# insert some categories
cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 1.1' 
cell = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 1.2 - limit'
cell = sheet.cell(row=3, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2'
cell = sheet.cell(row=4, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2.1 - extra'
cell = sheet.cell(row=5, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2.2 - extra2'

# insert some values
for i in range(5):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
    cell.value = i+2

# create chart
chart = BarChart()

values = Reference(sheet, min_col = 2, min_row = 1,
                         max_col = 2, max_row = 5)

bar_categories = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=5)
chart.add_data(values)
chart.set_categories(bar_categories)

chart.title = " BAR-CHART "
chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.title = " X_AXIS "
chart.y_axis.title = " Y_AXIS "
sheet.add_chart(chart, "E2")
 
# save the file
wb.save("barChart.xlsx")
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40146418) related?

Comment: @BigBen, it is. Thanks.